# Can a digital piano be dismantled to be used as a portable keyboard?

Tags: digital-piano

Pretty much the title, so apologies if this sounds silly but I couldn't find any information elsewhere.

I'm an absolute beginner to the piano and was eyeing this amazing deal on a digital piano. But I'll be moving quite a bit and my hostel rooms don't really have that much space, so can the digital piano be dismantled off the cabinet and used as a portable keyboard?

Edit: It is a NUX WK-520

Comment: How could anyone answer this without you at least giving the exact brand/model number? Really you should ask the maker or get a technical diagram that shows its construction. Your idea of "dismantle" might not involve a saw.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I edited the post with the spec

Comment: That helps. But did you read a description of it? The Amazon description says it ships in two parcels, piano and bench. Pictures sort of look like the piano parts detaches from the stand. I wouldn't take anyone's word on it other than the manufacturer or seller. Keep in mind the pedals below and how they _might_ require a connection through the stand.

Comment: Yes. But it looks like you won't be able to use the pedal unit. Also mounting it on a portable stand might actually take up *more* space than just mounting it on the cabinet.

Comment: To get a definitive view you will need to ask the supplier. This is not really on topic here, despite John's excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Nux WK520 is a furniture style piano. That will create a few issues for you. First it weighs about 48kg (over 100 lbs) and most of that weight is in the casing of the piano so you will be dealing with a very heavy instrument that really is not much smaller or lighter than it would be with the lower stand portion removed.

The upper piano portion is easy to remove from the stand, it just requires removing 4 screws but the other problem is that the pedals are part of the base and the pedal assembly is almost certainly proprietary so that means you probably can’t use an off the rack universal sustain pedal with it.

These 2 issues make using this piano as a portable problematic at best.

Here is a link to the page that describes the piano and if you scroll to the bottom there is a user manual there as well which may have useful information for you: https://www.nuxefx.com/wk-520.html

Comment: I looked at the manual and there is no standard 1/4” sustain pedal jack, so I agree there would be no pedals if used without the cabinet. The cabinet part could be quite heavy so perhaps without it the keyboard alone might be as little as half the total weight. Still very heavy for fitting a “portable” goal.

Comment: @ToddWilcox. I recently bought a Yamaha Clavinova with a much more substantial lower case and when assembling it I discovered even that is much lighter than the upper section. I would guess 3/4 of the weight is in the top.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how it's constructed.

Take the legs off mine & you still wouldn't want to carry it on your own, it's made of thick wood, not plastic. It also has the speakers suspended from the underside of the case, so it won't rest flat. Look for a portable keyboard if you want portable.

Comment: @HashimIshfaq Note, if we're talking about a full 88-key keyboard with standard-size keys, then everything is going to be the same length, whether we call it a "digital piano" or "keyboard." If you really want to keep the dimensions down, look into products with a smaller range.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of portable electronic keyboards that just use a stand. They're as good as what you're looking at, maybe not such a good deal, though. Moving around a lot, you'll be better off with one of those, with its own case and stand (and maybe speakers), so it could even be stored if space is that tight. You're not going to find one that looks like a real piano, that is easily dismantlable. The last one I bought was a Roland FP5, 88 keys, nice action, and around £400. Bet the one you're looking at is more than that!

Comment: @HashimIshfaq Oh yeah, and if you're in a hostel, it might be better to skip the speakers entirely and use headphones!

Comment: Yeah I was going for a portable keyboard too but the online seller I found is giving this particular digital piano for around $230, ik its too good to be true so it probably is :) so that's why I got a bit excited. But I'll see, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @HashimIshfaq I have no idea how good this model is, but it looks like it retails for around $900 USD, so I'd be skeptical of the seller; perhaps it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

With portability in mind I‘d like to suggest a different route. Consider using:

- a master keyboard (i.e. just the keys, no sound), with key bed you desire (there are some mimicking mechanics, at a price)
- separate pedals (just Midi switches; there are some which provide an analog value)
- a portable computer
- THE sound: Pianoteq https://www.modartt.com/pianoteq
- some cables
- headphones
- some stand and bags.

Listen to the demos at modartt, and scan through their technology. To my knowledge, it’s the only `physical simulator` of strings and sound propagation, with nice analog post processing, like EQ, reverb etc. You’ll hear that. Also the effects of non-switching, i.e. almost analog, pedal action, or a hard hit of a key. // *And that’s why this is a hint, no ad …*

In terms of overall-weight it may stay well below the 25 kg level. It’s a bit more bits and pieces, if at all. Moneywise you’ll end up somewhere around 1000 EUR, when having all modules. Just calculate your (growing) needs.